# Why is my Form Load rule not changing a value?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

My InfoPath form has several sections that I've configured to be hidden when associated checkboxes are checked.

When the form *opens* on SharePoint, I want the values of these checkboxes to be set to TRUE, thus having all sections hidden.

In InfoPath, I created a rule for Form Load to change one of these values as a test but it's not hiding the corresponding section. The only noticeable difference is that the checkbox has a red outline.

[image]

Any thoughts on a solution are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of scenarios why rule fails on form load - may be you have sequence of rules in the form load,  due to the that first it is hiding then due to the affect of next rule it displaying again... so to avoid this, order the rules in proper way as per the condition and logic.

Regarding the checkbox why it is showing as red mark - check the condition of checkbox value whether it is correctly set. For example, instead setting the condition with **true** or  **false** might have set **yes** or **no**,most probably infopath checks 0 or 1 for checkbox. So, you could these possibilities.

Comment: Now that I got it to work, I didn't think it through and now see that collapsing everything is going to disrupt the user too much because they'll have to go into edit mode to uncheck what they need to see. But now that I've removed that rule, the form will no longer save the checkboxes that have either been manually checked/unchecked. It always reverts to expanding everything. Is the form somehow not updating correctly?

Comment: Oh and thanks, btw. :) I did try removing the checkboxes to basically start over, but that doesn't seem to work at all either.

Comment: One more thing, just testing on one checkbox, I noticed that no matter if it is checked or unchecked, the value in the list view is always "Yes". It's just not saving the value back to the data, which is odd.